# Deserialisation error on worker in standalone Spark cluster

Tags: hadoop, serialization, apache-spark

I have a spark application that works fine on a standalone Spark cluster that runs ok when the Spark cluster runs on my laptop 
(master and one worker), but fails when I try to run in on a standalone Spark cluster 
deployed on EC2 (master and worker are on different machines). 
The application structure goes in the following way: 
There is a java process ('message processor') that runs on the same machine as 
Spark master.  When it starts, it submits itself to Spark master, then, 
it listens on SQS and on each received message, it should run a spark job to process a file from S3, which address is configured in the message . 
It looks like all this fails at the point where the Spark driver tries to send the job 
to the Spark executer. 
Below is the code from the 'message processor' that configures the SparkContext, 
Then the Spark driver log, and then the Spark executor log. 
The outputs of my code and some important points are marked in bold and 
I've simplified the code and logs in some places for the sake of readability. 
Would appreciate your help very much, because I've run out of ideas with this problem.

'message processor' code: 
logger.info("Started Integration Hub SubmitDriver in test mode.");

```
SparkConf sparkConf = new SparkConf() 
.setMaster(SPARK_MASTER_URI) 
.setAppName(APPLICATION_NAME) 
.setSparkHome(SPARK_LOCATION_ON_EC2_MACHINE); 

sparkConf.setJars(JavaSparkContext.jarOfClass(this.getClass())); 

// configure spark executor to use log4j properties located in the local spark conf dir 
sparkConf.set("spark.executor.extraJavaOptions", "-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -Dlog4j.configuration=log4j_integrationhub_sparkexecutor.properties"); 

sparkConf.set("spark.executor.memory", "1g"); 
sparkConf.set("spark.cores.max", "3"); 
// Spill shuffle to disk to avoid OutOfMemory, at cost of reduced performance 
sparkConf.set("spark.shuffle.spill", "true"); 

logger.info("Connecting Spark"); 
JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(sparkConf); 

sc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3n.awsAccessKeyId", AWS_KEY); 
sc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3n.awsSecretAccessKey", AWS_SECRET); 

logger.info("Spark connected");
```

Driver log:

```
2015-05-01 07:47:14 INFO  ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner:239 - JSR-330 'javax.inject.Named' annotation found and supported for component scanning 
2015-05-01 07:47:14 INFO  AnnotationConfigApplicationContext:510 - Refreshing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@5540b23b: startup date [Fri May 01 07:47:14 UTC 2015]; root of context hierarchy 
2015-05-01 07:47:14 INFO  AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor:140 - JSR-330 'javax.inject.Inject' annotation found and supported for autowiring 
2015-05-01 07:47:14 INFO  DefaultListableBeanFactory:596 - Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@13f948e: defining beans [org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor,integrationHubConfig,org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.importAwareProcessor,processorInlineDriver,s3Accessor,cdFetchUtil,httpUtil,cdPushUtil,submitDriver,databaseLogger,connectorUtil,totangoDataValidations,environmentConfig,sesUtil,processorExecutor,processorDriver]; root of factory hierarchy 
2015-05-01 07:47:15 INFO  SubmitDriver:69 - Started Integration Hub SubmitDriver in test mode. 
2015-05-01 07:47:15 INFO  SubmitDriver:101 - Connecting Spark 
2015-05-01 07:47:15 INFO  SparkContext:59 - Running Spark version 1.3.0 
2015-05-01 07:47:16 WARN  NativeCodeLoader:62 - Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable 
2015-05-01 07:47:16 INFO  SecurityManager:59 - Changing view acls to: hadoop 
2015-05-01 07:47:16 INFO  SecurityManager:59 - Changing modify acls to: hadoop 
2015-05-01 07:47:16 INFO  SecurityManager:59 - SecurityManager: authentication disabled; ui acls disabled; users with view permissions: Set(hadoop); users with modify permissions: Set(hadoop) 
2015-05-01 07:47:18 INFO  Slf4jLogger:80 - Slf4jLogger started 
2015-05-01 07:47:18 INFO  Remoting:74 - Starting remoting 
2015-05-01 07:47:18 INFO  Remoting:74 - Remoting started; listening on addresses :[akka.tcp://sparkDriver@sparkMasterIp:39176] 
2015-05-01 07:47:18 INFO  Utils:59 - Successfully started service 'sparkDriver' on port 39176. 
2015-05-01 07:47:18 INFO  SparkEnv:59 - Registering MapOutputTracker 
2015-05-01 07:47:18 INFO  SparkEnv:59 - Registering BlockManagerMaster 
2015-05-01 07:47:18 INFO  HttpFileServer:59 - HTTP File server directory is /tmp/spark-e4726219-5708-48c9-8377-c103ad1e7a75/httpd-fe68500f-01b1-4241-a3a2-3b4cf8394daf 
2015-05-01 07:47:18 INFO  HttpServer:59 - Starting HTTP Server 
2015-05-01 07:47:19 INFO  Server:272 - jetty-8.y.z-SNAPSHOT 
2015-05-01 07:47:19 INFO  AbstractConnector:338 - Started SocketConnector@0.0.0.0:47166 
2015-05-01 07:47:19 INFO  Utils:59 - Successfully started service 'HTTP file server' on port 47166. 
2015-05-01 07:47:19 INFO  SparkEnv:59 - Registering OutputCommitCoordinator 
2015-05-01 07:47:24 INFO  Server:272 - jetty-8.y.z-SNAPSHOT 
2015-05-01 07:47:24 INFO  AbstractConnector:338 - Started SelectChannelConnector@0.0.0.0:4040 
2015-05-01 07:47:24 INFO  Utils:59 - Successfully started service 'SparkUI' on port 4040. 
2015-05-01 07:47:24 INFO  SparkUI:59 - Started SparkUI at http://sparkMasterIp:4040
2015-05-01 07:47:24 INFO  SparkContext:59 - Added JAR /rev/8fcc3a5/integhub_be/genconn/lib/genconn-8fcc3a5.jar at http://sparkMasterIp:47166/jars/genconn-8fcc3a5.jar with timestamp 1430466444838 
2015-05-01 07:47:24 INFO  AppClient$ClientActor:59 - Connecting to master akka.tcp://sparkMaster@sparkMasterIp:7077/user/Master... 
2015-05-01 07:47:25 INFO  AppClient$ClientActor:59 - Executor added: app-20150501074725-0005/0 on worker-20150430140019-ip-sparkWorkerIp-38610 (sparkWorkerIp:38610) with 1 cores 
2015-05-01 07:47:25 INFO  AppClient$ClientActor:59 - Executor updated: app-20150501074725-0005/0 is now LOADING 
2015-05-01 07:47:25 INFO  AppClient$ClientActor:59 - Executor updated: app-20150501074725-0005/0 is now RUNNING 
2015-05-01 07:47:25 INFO  NettyBlockTransferService:59 - Server created on 34024 
2015-05-01 07:47:26 INFO  SubmitDriver:116 - Spark connected 
2015-05-01 07:47:26 INFO  SubmitDriver:125 - Connected to SQS... Listening on https://sqsAddress
2015-05-01 07:51:39 INFO  SubmitDriver:130 - Polling Message queue... 
2015-05-01 07:51:47 INFO  SubmitDriver:148 - Received Message : {someMessage} 
2015-05-01 07:51:47 INFO  SubmitDriver:158 - Process Input JSON 
2015-05-01 07:51:50 INFO  SparkContext:59 - Created broadcast 0 from textFile at ProcessorDriver.java:208 
2015-05-01 07:51:52 INFO  FileInputFormat:253 - Total input paths to process : 1 
2015-05-01 07:51:52 INFO  SparkContext:59 - Starting job: first at ConnectorUtil.java:605 
2015-05-01 07:51:52 INFO  SparkContext:59 - Created broadcast 1 from broadcast at DAGScheduler.scala:839 
2015-05-01 07:51:52 WARN  TaskSetManager:71 - ... *the warning will be repeated as error below*
2015-05-01 07:51:52 ERROR TaskSetManager:75 - Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 4 times; aborting job 
2015-05-01 07:51:52 ERROR ProcessorDriver:261 - Error executing the batch Operation.. 
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 0.0 (TID 3, sparkWorkerIp): java.io.EOFException 
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.readFully(ObjectInputStream.java:2744) 
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readFully(ObjectInputStream.java:1032) 
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.DataOutputBuffer$Buffer.write(DataOutputBuffer.java:63) 
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.DataOutputBuffer.write(DataOutputBuffer.java:101) 
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.UTF8.readChars(UTF8.java:216) 
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.UTF8.readString(UTF8.java:208) 
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileSplit.readFields(FileSplit.java:87) 
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.ObjectWritable.readObject(ObjectWritable.java:237) 
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.ObjectWritable.readFields(ObjectWritable.java:66) 
        at org.apache.spark.SerializableWritable$$anonfun$readObject$1.apply$mcV$sp(SerializableWritable.scala:43) 
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryOrIOException(Utils.scala:1137) 
        at org.apache.spark.SerializableWritable.readObject(SerializableWritable.scala:39) 
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) 
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) 
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) 
        at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1017) 
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1893) 
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1798) 
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1350) 
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1990) 
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1915) 
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1798) 
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1350) 
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1990) 
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1915) 
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1798) 
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1350) 
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:370) 
        at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaDeserializationStream.readObject(JavaSerializer.scala:68) 
        at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializerInstance.deserialize(JavaSerializer.scala:94) 
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:185) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) 
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) 

Driver stacktrace: ...
```

Worker log:

```
2015-05-01 07:47:26 INFO  CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend:47 - Registered signal handlers for [TERM, HUP, INT] 
2015-05-01 07:47:26 DEBUG Configuration:227 - java.io.IOException: config() 
        at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.<init>(Configuration.java:227) 
        at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.<init>(Configuration.java:214) 
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkHadoopUtil.newConfiguration(SparkHadoopUtil.scala:78) 
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkHadoopUtil.<init>(SparkHadoopUtil.scala:43) 
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkHadoopUtil$.<init>(SparkHadoopUtil.scala:220) 
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkHadoopUtil$.<clinit>(SparkHadoopUtil.scala) 
        at org.apache.spark.executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend$.run(CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend.scala:128) 
        at org.apache.spark.executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend$.main(CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend.scala:224) 
        at org.apache.spark.executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend.main(CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend.scala) 

2015-05-01 07:47:26 DEBUG Groups:139 -  Creating new Groups object 
2015-05-01 07:47:27 DEBUG Groups:59 - Group mapping impl=org.apache.hadoop.security.ShellBasedUnixGroupsMapping; cacheTimeout=300000 
2015-05-01 07:47:27 DEBUG Configuration:227 - java.io.IOException: config() 
        at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.<init>(Configuration.java:227) 
        at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.<init>(Configuration.java:214) 
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.ensureInitialized(UserGroupInformation.java:184) 
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.isSecurityEnabled(UserGroupInformation.java:236) 
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.KerberosName.<clinit>(KerberosName.java:79) 
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.initialize(UserGroupInformation.java:209) 
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.setConfiguration(UserGroupInformation.java:226) 
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkHadoopUtil.<init>(SparkHadoopUtil.scala:44) 
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkHadoopUtil$.<init>(SparkHadoopUtil.scala:220) 
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkHadoopUtil$.<clinit>(SparkHadoopUtil.scala) 
        at org.apache.spark.executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend$.run(CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend.scala:128) 
        at org.apache.spark.executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend$.main(CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend.scala:224) 
        at org.apache.spark.executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend.main(CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend.scala) 

2015-05-01 07:47:27 DEBUG SparkHadoopUtil:63 - running as user: hadoop 
2015-05-01 07:47:27 DEBUG UserGroupInformation:146 - hadoop login 
2015-05-01 07:47:27 DEBUG UserGroupInformation:95 - hadoop login commit 
2015-05-01 07:47:27 DEBUG UserGroupInformation:125 - using local user:UnixPrincipal: root 
2015-05-01 07:47:27 DEBUG UserGroupInformation:493 - UGI loginUser:root 
2015-05-01 07:47:27 DEBUG UserGroupInformation:1143 - PriviledgedAction as:hadoop from:org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkHadoopUtil.runAsSparkUser(SparkHadoopUtil.scala:59) 
2015-05-01 07:47:27 INFO  SecurityManager:59 - Changing view acls to: root,hadoop 
2015-05-01 07:47:27 INFO  SecurityManager:59 - Changing modify acls to: root,hadoop 
2015-05-01 07:47:27 INFO  SecurityManager:59 - SecurityManager: authentication disabled; ui acls disabled; users with view permissions: Set(root, hadoop); users with modify permissions: Set(root, hadoop) 
2015-05-01 07:47:27 DEBUG SecurityManager:63 - SSLConfiguration for file server: SSLOptions{enabled=false, keyStore=None, keyStorePassword=None, trustStore=None, trustStorePassword=None, protocol=None, enabledAlgorithms=Set()} 
2015-05-01 07:47:27 DEBUG SecurityManager:63 - SSLConfiguration for Akka: SSLOptions{enabled=false, keyStore=None, keyStorePassword=None, trustStore=None, trustStorePassword=None, protocol=None, enabledAlgorithms=Set()} 
2015-05-01 07:47:27 DEBUG AkkaUtils:63 - In createActorSystem, requireCookie is: off 
2015-05-01 07:47:28 INFO  Slf4jLogger:80 - Slf4jLogger started 
2015-05-01 07:47:28 INFO  Remoting:74 - Starting remoting 
2015-05-01 07:47:29 INFO  Remoting:74 - Remoting started; listening on addresses :[akka.tcp://driverPropsFetcher@sparkWorkerIp:49741] 
2015-05-01 07:47:29 INFO  Utils:59 - Successfully started service 'driverPropsFetcher' on port 49741. 
2015-05-01 07:47:29 INFO  RemoteActorRefProvider$RemotingTerminator:74 - Shutting down remote daemon. 
2015-05-01 07:47:29 INFO  RemoteActorRefProvider$RemotingTerminator:74 - Remote daemon shut down; proceeding with flushing remote transports. 
2015-05-01 07:47:29 INFO  SecurityManager:59 - Changing view acls to: root,hadoop 
2015-05-01 07:47:29 INFO  SecurityManager:59 - Changing modify acls to: root,hadoop 
2015-05-01 07:47:29 INFO  SecurityManager:59 - SecurityManager: authentication disabled; ui acls disabled; users with view permissions: Set(root, hadoop); users with modify permissions: Set(root, hadoop) 
2015-05-01 07:47:29 DEBUG SecurityManager:63 - SSLConfiguration for file server: SSLOptions{enabled=false, keyStore=None, keyStorePassword=None, trustStore=None, trustStorePassword=None, protocol=None, enabledAlgorithms=Set()} 
2015-05-01 07:47:29 DEBUG SecurityManager:63 - SSLConfiguration for Akka: SSLOptions{enabled=false, keyStore=None, keyStorePassword=None, trustStore=None, trustStorePassword=None, protocol=None, enabledAlgorithms=Set()} 
2015-05-01 07:47:29 DEBUG AkkaUtils:63 - In createActorSystem, requireCookie is: off 
2015-05-01 07:47:29 INFO  RemoteActorRefProvider$RemotingTerminator:74 - Remoting shut down. 
2015-05-01 07:47:29 INFO  Slf4jLogger:80 - Slf4jLogger started 
2015-05-01 07:47:29 INFO  Remoting:74 - Starting remoting 
2015-05-01 07:47:29 INFO  Remoting:74 - Remoting started; listening on addresses :[akka.tcp://sparkExecutor@ sparkWorkerIp:45299] 
2015-05-01 07:47:29 INFO  Utils:59 - Successfully started service 'sparkExecutor' on port 45299. 
2015-05-01 07:47:29 DEBUG SparkEnv:63 - Using serializer: class org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializer 
2015-05-01 07:47:29 INFO  AkkaUtils:59 - Connecting to MapOutputTracker: akka.tcp://sparkDriver@ sparkMasterIp:39176/user/MapOutputTracker 
2015-05-01 07:47:30 INFO  AkkaUtils:59 - Connecting to BlockManagerMaster: akka.tcp://sparkDriver@sparkMasterIp:39176/user/BlockManagerMaster 
2015-05-01 07:47:30 INFO  DiskBlockManager:59 - Created local directory at /mnt/spark/spark-d745cbac-d1cc-47ee-9eba-e99e104732d5/spark-e3963fa3-cab6-4c69-8e78-d23246250a5d/spark-6f1a9653-86fd-401f-bf37-6eca5b6c0adf/blockmgr-ee0e9452-4111-42d0-ab5e-e66317052e4b 
2015-05-01 07:47:30 INFO  MemoryStore:59 - MemoryStore started with capacity 548.5 MB 
2015-05-01 07:47:30 INFO  AkkaUtils:59 - Connecting to OutputCommitCoordinator: akka.tcp://sparkDriver@ sparkMasterIp:39176/user/OutputCommitCoordinator 
2015-05-01 07:47:30 INFO  CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend:59 - Connecting to driver: akka.tcp://sparkDriver@ sparkMasterIp:39176/user/CoarseGrainedScheduler 
2015-05-01 07:47:30 INFO  WorkerWatcher:59 - Connecting to worker akka.tcp://sparkWorker@sparkWorkerIp:38610/user/Worker 
2015-05-01 07:47:30 DEBUG WorkerWatcher:50 - [actor] received message Associated [akka.tcp://sparkExecutor@ sparkWorkerIp:45299] -> [akka.tcp://sparkWorker@ sparkWorkerIp:38610] from Actor[akka://sparkExecutor/deadLetters] 
2015-05-01 07:47:30 INFO  WorkerWatcher:59 - Successfully connected to akka.tcp://sparkWorker@ sparkWorkerIp:38610/user/Worker 
2015-05-01 07:47:30 DEBUG WorkerWatcher:56 - [actor] handled message (1.18794 ms) Associated [akka.tcp://sparkExecutor@ sparkWorkerIp:45299] -> [akka.tcp://sparkWorker@ sparkWorkerIp:38610] from Actor[akka://sparkExecutor/deadLetters] 
2015-05-01 07:47:30 DEBUG CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend:50 - [actor] received message RegisteredExecutor from Actor[akka.tcp://sparkDriver@ sparkMasterIp:39176/user/CoarseGrainedScheduler#-970636338] 
2015-05-01 07:47:30 INFO  CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend:59 - Successfully registered with driver 
2015-05-01 07:47:30 INFO  Executor:59 - Starting executor ID 0 on host sparkWorkerIp 
2015-05-01 07:47:30 DEBUG InternalLoggerFactory:71 - Using SLF4J as the default logging framework 
2015-05-01 07:47:30 DEBUG PlatformDependent0:76 - java.nio.Buffer.address: available 
2015-05-01 07:47:30 DEBUG PlatformDependent0:76 - sun.misc.Unsafe.theUnsafe: available 
2015-05-01 07:47:30 DEBUG PlatformDependent0:71 - sun.misc.Unsafe.copyMemory: available 
2015-05-01 07:47:30 DEBUG PlatformDependent0:76 - java.nio.Bits.unaligned: true 
2015-05-01 07:47:30 DEBUG PlatformDependent:76 - UID: 0 
2015-05-01 07:47:30 DEBUG PlatformDependent:76 - Java version: 7 
2015-05-01 07:47:30 DEBUG PlatformDependent:76 - -Dio.netty.noUnsafe: false 
2015-05-01 07:47:30 DEBUG PlatformDependent:76 - sun.misc.Unsafe: available 
2015-05-01 07:47:30 DEBUG PlatformDependent:76 - -Dio.netty.noJavassist: false 
2015-05-01 07:47:30 DEBUG PlatformDependent:71 - Javassist: unavailable 
2015-05-01 07:47:30 DEBUG PlatformDependent:71 - You don't have Javassist in your class path or you don't have enough permission to load dynamically generated classes.  Please check the configuration for better performance. 
2015-05-01 07:47:30 DEBUG PlatformDependent:76 - -Dio.netty.tmpdir: /tmp (java.io.tmpdir) 
2015-05-01 07:47:30 DEBUG PlatformDependent:76 - -Dio.netty.bitMode: 64 (sun.arch.data.model) 
2015-05-01 07:47:30 DEBUG PlatformDependent:76 - -Dio.netty.noPreferDirect: false 
2015-05-01 07:47:30 DEBUG MultithreadEventLoopGroup:76 - -Dio.netty.eventLoopThreads: 2 
2015-05-01 07:47:30 DEBUG NioEventLoop:76 - -Dio.netty.noKeySetOptimization: false 
2015-05-01 07:47:30 DEBUG NioEventLoop:76 - -Dio.netty.selectorAutoRebuildThreshold: 512 
2015-05-01 07:47:30 DEBUG PooledByteBufAllocator:76 - -Dio.netty.allocator.numHeapArenas: 1 
2015-05-01 07:47:30 DEBUG PooledByteBufAllocator:76 - -Dio.netty.allocator.numDirectArenas: 1 
2015-05-01 07:47:30 DEBUG PooledByteBufAllocator:76 - -Dio.netty.allocator.pageSize: 8192 
2015-05-01 07:47:30 DEBUG PooledByteBufAllocator:76 - -Dio.netty.allocator.maxOrder: 11 
2015-05-01 07:47:30 DEBUG PooledByteBufAllocator:76 - -Dio.netty.allocator.chunkSize: 16777216 
2015-05-01 07:47:30 DEBUG PooledByteBufAllocator:76 - -Dio.netty.allocator.tinyCacheSize: 512 
2015-05-01 07:47:30 DEBUG PooledByteBufAllocator:76 - -Dio.netty.allocator.smallCacheSize: 256 
2015-05-01 07:47:30 DEBUG PooledByteBufAllocator:76 - -Dio.netty.allocator.normalCacheSize: 64 
2015-05-01 07:47:30 DEBUG PooledByteBufAllocator:76 - -Dio.netty.allocator.maxCachedBufferCapacity: 32768 
2015-05-01 07:47:30 DEBUG PooledByteBufAllocator:76 - -Dio.netty.allocator.cacheTrimInterval: 8192 
2015-05-01 07:47:30 DEBUG ThreadLocalRandom:71 - -Dio.netty.initialSeedUniquifier: 0x4ac460da6a283b82 (took 1 ms) 
2015-05-01 07:47:31 DEBUG ByteBufUtil:76 - -Dio.netty.allocator.type: unpooled 
2015-05-01 07:47:31 DEBUG ByteBufUtil:76 - -Dio.netty.threadLocalDirectBufferSize: 65536 
2015-05-01 07:47:31 DEBUG NetUtil:86 - Loopback interface: lo (lo, 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1%1) 
2015-05-01 07:47:31 DEBUG NetUtil:81 - /proc/sys/net/core/somaxconn: 128 
2015-05-01 07:47:31 DEBUG TransportServer:106 - Shuffle server started on port :46839 
2015-05-01 07:47:31 INFO  NettyBlockTransferService:59 - Server created on 46839 
2015-05-01 07:47:31 INFO  BlockManagerMaster:59 - Trying to register BlockManager 
2015-05-01 07:47:31 INFO  BlockManagerMaster:59 - Registered BlockManager 
2015-05-01 07:47:31 INFO  AkkaUtils:59 - Connecting to HeartbeatReceiver: akka.tcp://sparkDriver@ sparkMasterIp:39176/user/HeartbeatReceiver 
2015-05-01 07:47:31 DEBUG CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend:56 - [actor] handled message (339.232401 ms) RegisteredExecutor from Actor[akka.tcp://sparkDriver@ sparkMasterIp:39176/user/CoarseGrainedScheduler#-970636338] 
2015-05-01 07:51:52 DEBUG CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend:50 - [actor] received message LaunchTask(org.apache.spark.util.SerializableBuffer@608752bf) from Actor[akka.tcp://sparkDriver@ sparkMasterIp:39176/user/CoarseGrainedScheduler#-970636338] 
2015-05-01 07:51:52 INFO  CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend:59 - Got assigned task 0 
2015-05-01 07:51:52 DEBUG CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend:56 - [actor] handled message (22.96474 ms) LaunchTask(org.apache.spark.util.SerializableBuffer@608752bf) from Actor[akka.tcp://sparkDriver@ sparkMasterIp:39176/user/CoarseGrainedScheduler#-970636338] 
2015-05-01 07:51:52 INFO  Executor:59 - Running task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0) 
2015-05-01 07:51:52 INFO  Executor:59 - Fetching http://sparkMasterIp:47166/jars/genconn-8fcc3a5.jar with timestamp 1430466444838 
2015-05-01 07:51:52 DEBUG Configuration:227 - java.io.IOException: config() 
        at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.<init>(Configuration.java:227) 
        at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.<init>(Configuration.java:214) 
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkHadoopUtil.newConfiguration(SparkHadoopUtil.scala:78) 
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor.hadoopConf$lzycompute$1(Executor.scala:356) 
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor.org$apache$spark$executor$Executor$$hadoopConf$1(Executor.scala:356) 
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$executor$Executor$$updateDependencies$5.apply(Executor.scala:375) 
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$executor$Executor$$updateDependencies$5.apply(Executor.scala:366) 
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:772) 
        at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(HashMap.scala:98) 
        at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(HashMap.scala:98) 
        at scala.collection.mutable.HashTable$class.foreachEntry(HashTable.scala:226) 
        at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap.foreachEntry(HashMap.scala:39) 
        at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap.foreach(HashMap.scala:98) 
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter.foreach(TraversableLike.scala:771) 
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor.org$apache$spark$executor$Executor$$updateDependencies(Executor.scala:366) 
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:184) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) 
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) 

2015-05-01 07:51:52 DEBUG Utils:63 - fetchFile not using security 
2015-05-01 07:51:52 INFO  Utils:59 - Fetching http://sparkMasterIp:47166/jars/genconn-8fcc3a5.jar to /mnt/spark/spark-d745cbac-d1cc-47ee-9eba-e99e104732d5/spark-e3963fa3-cab6-4c69-8e78-d23246250a5d/spark-0eabace1-ee89-48a3-9a71-0218f0ffc61c/fetchFileTemp2001054150131059247.tmp 
2015-05-01 07:51:52 INFO  Utils:59 - Copying /mnt/spark/spark-d745cbac-d1cc-47ee-9eba-e99e104732d5/spark-e3963fa3-cab6-4c69-8e78-d23246250a5d/spark-0eabace1-ee89-48a3-9a71-0218f0ffc61c/18615094621430466444838_cache to /mnt/spark-work/app-20150501074725-0005/0/./genconn-8fcc3a5.jar 
2015-05-01 07:51:52 INFO  Executor:59 - Adding file:/mnt/spark-work/app-20150501074725-0005/0/./genconn-8fcc3a5.jar to class loader 
2015-05-01 07:51:52 DEBUG Configuration:227 - java.io.IOException: config() 
        at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.<init>(Configuration.java:227) 
        at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.<init>(Configuration.java:214) 
        at org.apache.spark.SerializableWritable$$anonfun$readObject$1.apply$mcV$sp(SerializableWritable.scala:42) 
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryOrIOException(Utils.scala:1137) 
        at org.apache.spark.SerializableWritable.readObject(SerializableWritable.scala:39) 
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) 
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) 
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) 
        at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1017) 
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1893) 
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1798) 
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1350) 
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1990) 
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1915) 
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1798) 
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1350) 
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1990) 
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1915) 
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1798) 
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1350) 
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:370) 
        at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaDeserializationStream.readObject(JavaSerializer.scala:68) 
        at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializerInstance.deserialize(JavaSerializer.scala:94) 
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:185) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) 
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) 

2015-05-01 07:51:52 ERROR Executor:96 - Exception in task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0) 
*the error that is printed in the driver log*
```

...